# Unable to click on javascript element through selenium driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am using given below xpath but my script is not clicking on these element (python, scrapy, selenium)

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="MiniReport2"]/thead/tr/td[@class="Over" and contains(@onclick,"MenuClick")]')
```

**HTML Sample:**

```html
<table id="MiniReport2" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="Menu Unit" style="">            
            <thead>                
                <tr>                    
                    <td onmouseover="className='Over'" onmouseout="className=''" onclick="javascript:MenuClick('MiniReport2');" class="">
                         <div class="Plus">4. Report</div>                    
                    </td>                
                </tr>            
            </thead>            
</table>
```

Comment: Make sure to add the language tag, any error message that you got. So that it's easy to understand the issue and provide appropriate answer.

Comment: ok thank you, I'd just added

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Here is the xpath that you can use.

```
//table[@id='MiniReport2']//td[contains(@onclick,'MenuClick')]
```

Here is the script (I guess you are using python)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='MiniReport2']//td[contains(@onclick,'MenuClick')]").click()
```

If you want to click on `4. Report` then use the below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='MiniReport2']//td[contains(@onclick,'MenuClick')]/div[normalize-space(.)='4. Report']").click()
```

Comment: thanks your answer. I'd tried to 2 solutions but they did not work with errors:     >>> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id='MiniReport2']//td[contains(@onclick,'MenuClick')]/div[normalize-space(.)='4. Report']"}                     >>>selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id='MiniReport2']//td[contains(@onclick,'MenuClick')]/div[normalize-space(.)='4. Report']"}

Comment: Did you checked if there is any iframe which holding the table?

Comment: The phrase **Welcome to SO** appears to be a pure noise. Can you please remove the noise moving forward?

Comment: @DebanjanB With All Respect, Yes Sir!

Answer (score 0):

To handle dynamic element use `WebdriverWait` and following locator strategy.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element=WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//table[@class="Menu Unit"][starts-with(@id,"MiniReport")]//tr//td[contains(@onclick,"MenuClick")]/div[@class="Plus"][contains(.,"4. Report")]')))
element.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your solutions but I got more error. Please check it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/s20pmzgmdj110yi/sb%20error?dl=0.